# swift ask music permission for initial view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a split view controller with the top view controller set to a table view controller that is to display a list of playlists for selection.  The first time the app is loaded it asks for music access permission.  Answering yes does give it permission but the table view displays no playlists.  I end up having to kill the app and run it again.  Am I asking for music library permission the wrong place?  It is in that top view controller's viewWillAppear and store the playlists I'm using (since some are screened out) in a class of playlists.

```
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    checkMediaAccessAndSetup()
}

func checkMediaAccessAndSetup() {
    let authorizationStatus = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .notDetermined:
        // Show the permission prompt.
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization({[weak self] (newAuthorizationStatus: MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus) in
            // Try again after the prompt is dismissed.
            self?.checkMediaAccessAndSetup()
        })
    case .denied, .restricted:
        // Do not use MPMediaQuery.
        return
    default:
        // Proceed as usual.
        break
    }
    // Do stuff with MPMediaQuery
    self.setupPlaylistStore()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: As the MPMediaLibrary requestAuthorization block is implemented as [weak self], self may be nil inside the block. Are you sure that checkMediaAccessAndSetup method is getting called after requesting authorization on MPMediaLibrary?

Comment: It might be caused by `requestAuthorization` callback not being called on the main thread. Try calling `self?.checkMediaAccessAndSetup()` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`

Comment: Tried self.checkMediaAccessAndSetup() inside DispatchQueue.main.async {} inside viewWillAppear (it won't allow self?.checkMediaAccessAndSetup()).  Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chief problems with your code are

- You are completely failing to grapple with the fact that the `requestAuthorization` completion function is called on a background thread. You need to step out to the main thread to do work on the interface.
- You have omitted the all-important `.authorized` case. When you have work to do that depends upon your authorization status, you must do it *now* if you are authorized, but after authorization if you are not determined.

Thus, this is the correct scheme for a coherent authorization check (where `f()` is the thing you always want to do if you can):

```
let status = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
switch status {
case .authorized:
    f()
case .notDetermined:
    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
        if status == .authorized {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                f()
            }
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

If you abstract this code into a utility method, where `f` can be anything, you can do this *everywhere* in your app where authorization might be necessary — not merely at startup.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, yes I wasn't getting it but I do now.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the comments, it gave me clues of the multi-threading that was going on and I was able to fix it with a timer call if there were no playlists in the class to keep on checking and reload the table data.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    checkMediaAccess()
    self.setupPlaylistStore()
    tableView.reloadData()
    if store.allPlaylists.count < 1 {
        playlistTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:     #selector(self.playlistTimerCall), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

@objc func playlistTimerCall() {
    self.setupPlaylistStore()
    if store.allPlaylists.count > 1 {
        tableView.reloadData()
        playlistTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
func checkMediaAccess() {
    let authorizationStatus = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .notDetermined:
        // Show the permission prompt.
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization({[weak self] (newAuthorizationStatus: MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus) in
            // Try again after the prompt is dismissed.
            self?.checkMediaAccess()
        })
    case .denied, .restricted:
        // Do not use MPMediaQuery.
        return
    default:
        // Proceed as usual.
        break
    }
}


func setupPlaylistStore() {

    // purge store
    store.clearAllPlaylists()

    // create a query of media items in playlist
    let myPlayListsQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
    if myPlayListsQuery.collections != nil {
        playlists = myPlayListsQuery.collections!
    }

    // add playlists to MyPlaylist(s)
    if playlists.count > 0 {
        for index in 0...playlists.count - 1 {
            let playlist = playlists[index]
            store.addPlaylist(playlist: playlist as! MPMediaPlaylist)
        }
    }
    var toBeRemoved = [Int]()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if defaults.bool(forKey: "exclude_smart_playlists") {
        //smart
        for index in 0...(playlists.count - 1) {
            let playlist = playlists[index]
            let theAttributes = playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPlaylistAttributes) as! Int
            if theAttributes == 2 {
                toBeRemoved.append(index)
            }
        }
    }
    if defaults.bool(forKey: "exclude_folders") {
        //folders
        for index in 0...(playlists.count - 1) {
            let playlist = playlists[index]
            let isFolder = playlist.value(forProperty: "isFolder")
            let stringIsFolder = String("\(String(describing: isFolder))")
            if ((stringIsFolder.range(of: "1")) != nil) {
                toBeRemoved.append(index)
            }
        }
    }
    //sort from the last to the first so i don't reindex
    let reverseSortedPlaylists = toBeRemoved.sorted(by: >)

    // remove the unwanted playlists
    for list in reverseSortedPlaylists {
        store.removePlaylist(index: list)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't agree with this. Using a timer this way is just skanky. I have an app that displays playlists, and it has no need for such hacks. It's just a matter of doing things in the right order. Perhaps the problem lies in your `setupPlaylistStore`, which you have not shown.

Comment: Added the setupPlaylistStore.  I sort of agree but could see that everything was being called before any authorization was granted.  Open to other suggestions but the setup just kept on saying not authorized (yet).

Comment: "everything was being called before any authorization was granted" Sure, but your job is to cope coherently with that possibility, and to call everything again when authorization _is_ granted — as a _response_ to authorization _being_ granted (not in a _timer_, which just guesses when this might have happened).

Comment: I get that with things like location where there is locationManager for didChangeAuthorization but I'm not seeing such a thing for music library.

Comment: Well see my answer below. _Most_ authorization requests don't give you a `didChangeAuthorization` callback; location manager is the exception. What I'm giving you in my answer is a _completely general_ solution that works for all the other authorization types.